# spacy dependency parser trained on custom semantics produces label not in training data

Tags: python, spacy

I have trained a spacy model for POS tags and dependency labels with the dependency labels being a custom set of semantic labels.
When I load the trained model via `nlp = spacy.load('model-best')` and then run this code:

```
for t in nlp("some input text string"):
    print(t.dep_)
```

I see the label **dep** appear in some cases, even though that label is not part of my custom label vocabulary and therefore not present in the training data.

I only have a small training data set at this time, so I'm wondering if this is a default value that is output whenever the model doesn't have enough confidence to set one of the custom tags?

#### Info about spaCy

- **spaCy version:** 2.2.3
- **Platform:** Linux-4.4.0-18362-Microsoft-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
- **Python version:** 3.7.6

Comment: No, `dep` shouldn't show up as a default value. Are you sure you started with a blank model when training? If you did and you're still getting `dep`, I think this might be better addressed as a bug report where you can provide more details about the training data and how the model was trained: https://github.com/explosion/spacy/issues

Comment: @aab: thanks for your comment. I opened this issue https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5405

Comment: The solution is described here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5405
`dep` is used as a backoff if the model can't find a good label to be assigned from one of those provided in the training data